# How to run airflow scheduler and webserver simultaneously

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to run Airflow 2 locally with a postgres db (localhost). I can get the webserver running, however I can't get the scheduler to run at the same time as the webserver. Running `airflow scheduler` :

```
____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,543] {scheduler_job.py:709} INFO - Starting the scheduler
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,544] {scheduler_job.py:714} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times
[2022-08-27 16:10:50 -0500] [48113] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,546] {executor_loader.py:105} INFO - Loaded executor: SequentialExecutor
[2022-08-27 16:10:50 -0500] [48113] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:8793 (48113)
[2022-08-27 16:10:50 -0500] [48113] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,550] {manager.py:160} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 48114
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,552] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:10:50 -0500] [48115] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48115
[2022-08-27 16:10:50,556] {settings.py:55} INFO - Configured default timezone Timezone('UTC')
[2022-08-27T16:10:50.567-0500] {manager.py:406} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1.
[2022-08-27 16:10:50 -0500] [48116] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48116
[2022-08-27 16:15:50,663] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:20:50,749] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:25:50,834] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:30:50,911] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:35:50,991] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2022-08-27 16:40:51,064] {scheduler_job.py:1231} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
```

I can run the db, scheduler, and webserver using `airflow standalone`, however my understanding is this practice is really just for development, not for production so I want to avoid this. When initializing the database I have no issues. However when I go to the webserver UI, it will signal that no scheduler is running.  Then I am required to kill the UI to run `airflow scheduler` from the CLI.  Now per the code above, there isn't a point where control is returned back to my terminal from the scheduler without killing the scheduler, meaning I can't get back to the webserver UI. How can I then run the scheduler and run the webserver simultaneously without killing either process for the other?

Comment: how did you know that it is not fully executed? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: New to airflow so I'm not sure of typical time to completion for instantiating the scheduler, however I'm assuming that it's stalling here because it will sit at this point for several hours before I kill the process. Is there something I can do with the default DAGs that may change this? (i.e. remove them)

Comment: running the scheduler takes some minutes maximum, and for me, your scheduler is running, if you have a particular problem, I can help you to solve it. For the default DAGs, you can remove them by set `load_examples = False` in `airflow.cfg`, or by setting the environment var `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False` if you configure your server using environment variables.

Comment: @HusseinAwala If this scheduler is running as it should be, how might I be able to jump back to the webserver UI without shutting down the scheduler from the CLI? I went back and created a new env and am operating in ```airflow standalone``` which queues the db, scheduler, and webserver sequentially, but not sure how to get these to run outside of using ```airflow standalone```

Comment: `scheduler` and `webserver` are two separate components of Airflow, if your problem is with the webserver, you need just to run it in a second terminal `airflow webserver`, if you want to use the same terminal, you can run both in background: `airflow scheduler &` then `airflow webserver &`

Comment: This was an incredibly simple solution that I did not consider. YES OF COURSE A SECOND TERMINAL. Would you mind replying in response to the original post and I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow has multiple core components, like `wbeserver` and `scheduler`, these components run in separate processes, when you run `airflow standalone`, Airflow runs the `webserver`, the `scheduler` and the `triggerer` (a process which supports deferrable operators) in 3 processes ([check the source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py#L57-L88)).

If you want to run them manually, you should run each service in a separate terminal or run them in background:

```bash
airflow scheduler &
airflow webserver &
```